# Img inside Flexbox responsitivity issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have fragment of code with `flex` div, and an `img` inside it:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.item {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBI2.png" class="item">
</div>
```

On Chrome and IE, while I'm resizing window vertically, the image is only responsive in the vertical direction. The width is not changing proportionally to the height (decreasing in that case). On Firefox everything is OK.

Do you know this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/z2v9o9ew/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [viewports units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) if the container is going to take the entire screen size. And don't forget to set up the `height` for html and body tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/hsn43uzq/

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
.item {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500" class="item" />
</div>
```

As a workaround, you could drop `flex`, and use css `transform` for centering the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/5k84mfft/

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}
.item {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500" class="item" />
</div>
```

**Edit:** problem also can be solved by simply adding this as OP suggested, although we don't have a clue why it works.

```
flex-direction: column;
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c79g28xj/) and see the related comments underneath.

Comment: It works nice in this case. But I need img to always fit it's container. For example I would like to set .container width and height to 50%. img is escaping container in that case

Comment: Can you use background image with `background-size: contain`?

Comment: img may be scalled up then, would like to avoid such behaviour

Comment: I would like to avoid the second method, but you don't gues! I've asked on freenode css irc, and they said to add: flex-direction: column; It worked... css is weird. Just have to test on abit older browsers.

Comment: That is amazing `flex-direction: column;` just like that! good to know. Well, flex won't work on older IEs, and you'll have to use prefixes to get it work on Safari (yes even the newest version) - [caniuse flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: flexbox is buggy as hell! still doesn't work on IE, I've used your second answer and it works great, thanx!